# Add additional participants to an ongoing outlook email voting

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2016

I had sent out an outlook voting to a certain group at my workplace yesterday. I have already received a response from about 20 % of the recipients.

Today I realise that there are a few extra participants that need to be added to this voting which is already inprogress. I tried forwarding the original email to add a new participant, but his voting response was returned back to the new forwarded email only and did not consolidate with the rest of the results.

My question is - is there a way to add new participants to "this" email poll inprogress so that the results get consolidated automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid it is not feasible to add additional participants to a existent email poll in progress.

Given this situation, you may consider creating an additional message with vote buttons and send it to the remaining participants, then you can copy the tracking results of the two messages to Excel in order to view them together.

Comment: Although this response doesn't solve my problem, I am going to accept it as it seems to have answered my question. I haven't had any other responses which tell me otherwise. Thanks @yuki